# Cambiar el Android Gradle plugin a 11

Tags: android, flutter, vscode

Tengo un problema y es que no puedo ejecutar el `./gradlew signingReport`
porque me muestra el siguiente error `Android Gradle plugin requires Java 11 to run. You are currently using Java 1.8.` estoy usando Visual Studio Code

Gracias de antemano por cualquier ayuda

Comment: Puedes hacer un flutter doctor -v y mostrar lo que te imprime?

Comment: Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.3.10, on Microsoft Windows [Versi¢n 10.0.22621.963], locale es-CR)
[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 33.0.1)
[√] Chrome - develop for the web
[√] Visual Studio - develop for Windows (Visual Studio Community 2022 17.4.3)
[√] Android Studio (version 2021.3)
[√] VS Code (version 1.74.2)
[√] Connected device (3 available)
[√] HTTP Host Availability

Comment: chequea la respuesta: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66980512/android-studio-error-android-gradle-plugin-requires-java-11-to-run-you-are-cur

Comment: bro, no me sirve, porque yo estoy usando Visual estudio, no Android Studio

Comment: ya actualizaste el archivo build.gradle?

Comment: bro, pero cual de todos los que hay, eso es lo que busco

Comment: generalmente se encuentra en el directorio de Android del proyecto Flutter.
Busca el bloque 'com.android.application' en el archivo y localiza la línea 'com.android.application = 'com.android.application' '
Cambia el número de versión a 11. (ejemplo: com.android.application = '11.0.1'.)
guarda el archivo build.gradle y ejecute el comando flutter doctor nuevamente para verificar que el complemento Android Gradle se haya actualizado a la versión 11.

Comment: Bro, no encuentro eso

Comment: Sin importar que IDE estás usando Visual o Android, puedes abrir tu proyecto en Android Studio y hacer los cambios desde ahí, te dejo otro link... https://como-programar.net/errores/ionic-android-gradle-plugin-requires-java-11-to-run/

Comment: Viejo, en andorid estudio no me aparece eso que esta en la pagina de sdk de gridle

Comment: Básicamente el error te indica que debes instalar Java 11 en tu pc y luego debes cambiar el path para que apunte a dicha versión de Java. En Android Studio es diferente porque ya viene con Java 11 incluido, por así decirlo.